# Is my GPU being utilized in training? Keras

Tags: python, keras

Hi I am trying to use my 3060 to increase training speed,
I have install cudnn and nvidia drivers, (following YouTube tutorial)
I get the message in the terminal.)
I haven’t specified anything in my code as I have read keras will automatically use GPU if available.
However my training speed doesn’t seem to have changed by any noteable amount.

This is the message within the terminal once I run the code

```
2022-04-20 18:34:04.900724: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-04-20 18:34:05.477447: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9621 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
Epoch 1/500

2022-04-20 18:34:04.900724: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-04-20 18:34:05.477447: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9621 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
2022-04-20 18:35:00.079826: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded cuDNN version 8400
 1/41 [..............................] - ETA: 11:49 - loss: 0.3319
2022-04-20 18:34:04.900724: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-04-20 18:34:05.477447: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1525] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9621 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
2022-04-20 18:35:00.079826: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:368] Loaded cuDNN version 8400
2022-04-20 18:35:07.220634: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1786] TensorFloat-32 will be used for the matrix multiplication. This will only be logged once.
```

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you please the code where you are specifying that training in Keras to use GPU?

Comment: From the logs, it looks like the GPU is being used.

Comment: Bismark- I have not specified anywhere in my code specifically to use the GPU, from what i have seen on keras literature, there is no need to explicitly code in what device to use, keras does this automatically.
 
Jakub - Okay interesting, i guess it just isnt as impactful as i had anticipated.

Comment: @oz.vegas yeah it is detected but whether being used I cannot tell.  you can actually specify if you can using keras through tensorflow  with tf.device("gpu:0"):
   print("tf.keras code in this scope will run on GPU")

Comment: If there is no improvement in performance by using a GPU, that just means that compute was not the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

> You can check the availability of GPUs by the following code:
>
> ```
> import tensorflow as tf
> tf.test.gpu_device_name()
> ```
>
> if any GPUs are found to the environment, the name of the GPU will be
> shown:
> **/device:GPU:0**

Note: this is the advice mentioned in the book "The TENSORFLOW Workshop" by PacktPub.